# How to run schematics migration manually (from node_modules)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-schematics

We have multiple long living branches (per team) next to develop.
Now, if a team runs the schematics migrations from a library and update their code, it's possible that a different team (on a different branch) has new features that aren't updated by the schematics (because the new feature code obviously is not there).

Question: How can I run the schematics migration manually?
Obviously I can't just run `ng update` after merging the other changes because it will think that the project is already up to date.

I tried the following:

`schematics .:node_modules/url-to-library`

This does not do anything, not even throw an error. Any ideas?